# I need to have two upload buttons using this function

Tags: javascript

I'm using a file uploader called "upload-at-click" from: https://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/

It works good but the problem I'm having is I need two upload buttons on the page to upload two separate kinds of files. But I can only have one instance of the upclick() function, so I'm not sure how I can do this?

The code used for one button is:

```
  var element = document.createElement('input');
  element.value = 'Load CSV';
  element.id = 'uploader';
  element.type = 'button';
  stage.appendChild(element);
  upclick({
      element: element,
      action: '/mailer/file_upload.php',
      onstart: function (filename) {
          alert('Uploading: ' + filename);
      },
      oncomplete: function (response_data) {
          alert('Data upload complete.');
      }
  });
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I had no idea where to begin so I tried copying that and changing the var element name to a different name and then changing the upclick function name, but that didn't work of course.

Comment: Remember to add stuff like that into your question as you'll attract so many more responses if people realise you've exhausted all avenues yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass `element` as already existing element from DOM.

```
$('.uploadButton').click(function(){
   upclick({
      element : this // or maybe jQuery object $(this) ???
      /* rest of code */
   });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I understand the $('.uploadButton') part, is that referring to the element.id? Thanks

Comment: @user2721465 in upload-on-click at #3 there is element renamed to uploader and that uploader element is taken from DOM tree by id, so basically you can initiate multiple items at start of script runtime.